# WebStorm and MongoDB

Tags: port, webstorm, mean-stack

I'm now on the RESTful section of [The Web Developer Bootcamp](https://www.udemy.com/the-web-developer-bootcamp/) I am using MongoDB as my database along with Express to build a RESTful application (a blog). I was using cloud9 but decided to use WebStorm do to lack of sufficient space on cloud9. I have MongoDB up and running and can see content from my first test blog post using terminal command `db.blog.find()`.

The issue I am having is viewing the post in my browser using localhost. I'm uncertain what port I should be viewing in, I know that the default port for WebStorm is 63342 however when I go to port 63342 I get a 404 message.

Comment: `63342` is a default port for WebStorm's built-in simple we server. The general URL structure is: `localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/file.html`. If you want to use built-in web server .. you can just use  `Open in Browser` on your index.html -- with no deployment entry defined the built-in web server URL will be used. Have a look at this old blog post -- it should still be relevant: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/06/mean-stack-walkthrough-and-tips/

Comment: you are using Express to build your application - why do you open `localhost:63342` to access it? You need using the URL your Express server is listening on - `localhost:3000` or whatever it looks like